# Applying a seperate function to my Dataframe while also summing specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in which I have to summarize a lot of data and group it by three columns to summarize the data. A problem is that one specific column needs to have a specific formula applied to it as well.

My data looks like this:

```
Account Format  Network  Impressions Clicks Cost    Avg. position
Health1 Text     Search        2       0      0.5       1
Health1 Picture  Search        5       2      1        1.5
Health1 Picture  Search        1       2      3        2.4
Health1 Text     Search        1       0      0        2.3
Health1 Text     Display       2       0      0.7      1.7
Health2 Text     Display       0       0      0        3.3
Health2 Text     Display       2       2      4        3.3
Health2 Picture  Search        2       0      0        3.4
.....
```

So I need to group by the Account, Format and Network and summarize Impressions, Cost and Clicks like so, and summarize for each group:

```
Account Format  Network  Impressions Clicks Cost    Avg. position
Health1 Text     Search        3       0      0.5       x
Health1 Picture  Search        6       4      4         x
Health2 Text     Display       2       2      4         x
Health2 Picture  Search        2       0      0         x
.....
```

However, to calculate Avg. Position I need to apply a formula, my brain is kind of fried from working on stuff like this all day so any help would be a lifesaver. The Avg. Position column needs to have this formula applied to it:

> sum(impressions*Avg. Position)/sum(impressions)

My attempt was to multiply the Avg. Position column by impressions on a row to row basis, summarize the column along with the others and then divide by the summed impressions. This is not correct apparently, as it returns values < 1, which is not a possible output in the context of the data I am using.

```
frame['Avg. position'] = frame.apply(lambda x: (x['Impressions']*x['Avg. position']), axis=1)
frame = frame.groupby(['Account', 'Format', 'Network'])['Impressions','Clicks','Cost','Avg. position'].sum().reset_index()

frame['Avg. position'] = frame.apply(lambda x: (x['Avg. position']/x['Impressions']) if x['Impressions'] > 0 else '', axis=1)

frame.to_csv(yesterday_date+'.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use apply to update your "Avg. position" column is this:

```
denominator = frame['Impressions'].sum()
frame['Avg. position'] = frame[['Impressions', 'Avg. position']].apply(lambda x: x[0] * x[1] / denominator, axis=1)
```

BUT ... with Series objects you can use element-by-element operations:

```
frame['Avg. position'] = frame['Impressions'] * frame['Avg. position'] / frame['Impressions'].sum()
```

which means you could also do something like this:

```
frame['Cost'] = frame['Cost'] / 1000000
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with the groupby but it seems like you should have all the tools to figure it out now.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code for more clarity while you posted your answer. The 'Cost' line was not supposed to be there. My bad. To elaborate further, the groupby summarizes each row by Account, Format and Network. The formula for Avg. Position requires the sum of all Impressions per group as well as the sum of all rows Impressions * Avg. Position. i.e. this formula is on a per group basis.